# How to make an ArrayList stay at the initial capacity?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

How do I make an ArrayList not exceed a size of 3, as shown here:

`ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);`

Is there a certain method that will ensure the ArrayList does not grow past 3 entries?

I tried `ensureCapacity()`, `trimToSize()`, but they do not do what I want

Comment: At this point you might as well just use an array then. Arrays do not grow.

Comment: I want to use the ArrayList's prebuilt methods and an array will not work for my case

Comment: I suppose you could extend ArrayList and override the methods that add and replace elements.

Comment: this means I have to create my own methods. I am asking if there is anything available already that would prevent this

Comment: No, there's no Class that I know of that would put an artificial limit on cardinality.

Comment: @CrustyCrustecean you can use an array or implement custom a List for that

Comment: Does it have to be `java.util.ArrayList` specifically? Or are you ok with just `java.util.List`? Because if you are ok with that, then there are a couple of solutions available to you.

Comment: Otherwise, like the other commenters have said, the entire point of `java.util.ArrayList` was to make it easily resizable. It does not have the ability to turn that off. That would defeat the entire purpose of having an `ArrayList` at all. At that point, you would either use an array or an unmodifiable `List`.

Comment: I want to be able to use `contains()` of the ArrayList class on a simple array. Is there such a thing. I don't want to use ArrayList cause it won't stop growing

Comment: Nobody has mentioned this yet ... but the *capacity* of an `ArrayList` is not the same as its *size*.  They are different concepts.  For example, `new ArrayList<>(3)` creates a list whose initial size is `0` ... as returned by the `size()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't offer something like that. Maybe [Collections.unmodifiableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) could be something close, but it doesn't let you add, update or remove elements, just read the values from an already initialized list.

You have [FixedSizeList from Apache commons collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/FixedSizeList.html). You can only set values in specific positions, but you can't add or remove them